# why 'eslint --fix' useless

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I use eslint in my project to format code.

This is my config in package.json:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [

      "react-app",

      "react-app/jest"

    ]

  }
```

`"lint-fix": "eslint --fix --ext .tsx,.ts src/"`

When I run `npm run lint-fix`

only show some 'eqeqeq' warning. But not fixed

Comment: Per https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq only _some_ violations are auto-fixable.

Comment: ESLint will only fix lint errors if they are deemed to be "fixable". Which they can be if they don't break your code by fixing.

eqeqeq is one of the rules that is not autofixable as theres a difference between how != and !== is intepreted internally, and it can break your code in certain cases by doing it incorrectly. So ESLint will not auto fix all warnings.

Read more about why eqeqeq cannot be autofixed here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4578

Comment: @Daniel Olsen
Thank you ! I saw from the last comment that 'eqeqeq' auto-fixed was closed.